# How can I find square brackets in SQL by LIKE expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, escaping, sql-like

I need to find by sequence which contains symbols `[]` like `!@#$%^&[]{}<>?/,.*(^` with a `like` expression in [SQL Server 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2014).

How I can escape brackets to find records which contain the target string?

Example

```
SELECT *
FROM [TARGET_TABLE]
WHERE [TARGET COLUMN] LIKE '%"!@#$^&[]{}<>?/,.*(^"%';
```

`[TARGET TABLE]` has a row with `[TARGET COLUMN]` which value is

```
some text "!@#$^&[]{}<>?/,.*(^"
```

but the result of the expression is empty.

I know `[]` is a wildcard, but how can I escape brackets to find strings with them?

Comment: I don't know the exact details of sql-server implementation, but `'%\[\]%'` would do the job (this will be the case in Oracle and MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` has an escape character, which, by default is `\`.  You can set it to something else.  So this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TARGET_TABLE] 
WHERE [TARGET COLUMN] LIKE '%"!@#$^\[\]{}<>?/,.*(^"%';
```

You can set it to another character, but it is hard to choose one given your characters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TARGET_TABLE] 
WHERE [TARGET COLUMN] LIKE '%"!@#$^+[+]{}<>?/,.*(^"%' ESCAPE '+'
```

But, if you want to be more general, perhaps you want `^` for a character set.  For instance to get a column that contains any non-alphnumeric character:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TARGET_TABLE] 
WHERE [TARGET COLUMN] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%';
```

Or, if you want to find columns that *only* contain non-alphanumeric characters:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TARGET_TABLE] 
WHERE [TARGET COLUMN] NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%';
```

This idea can, of course, be extended to other sets of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the left bracket inside a class as `[[]`. When a closing bracket is not closing a class it is treated as a literal. (I'm using the word *class* as terminology from regexes where I think the SQL Server documentation just refers to this as a *set*.)

```
LIKE '%"!@#$^&[[]]{}<>?/,.*(^"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```
Create Table #Rohit (VarcharValues varchar(255))
Insert into #Rohit values
('"!@#$^&[]{}<>?/,.*(^"')
```

Then this:

```
SELECT * FROM [#Rohit] WHERE VarcharValues LIKE '%"!@#$^&\[]%' Escape '\'
```